# How to write symbols "momentum" in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

[image]

How to write symbols "momentum" in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Does it differs from a lowercase p? `\(p\)`.

Comment: just looks like `p`

Comment: I see a hook at the top. I would like to repeat

Comment: The hook at the top is a choice of the font.  For the default fonts, `p` doesn't have it, but `$p$` does.  So as long as you're having your momentum typeset as math, it will have the hook at the top.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you very much you helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[\dot{p}_{\parallel}=e\overline{E}_{\parallel}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The “hook” is a choice of the font designer. In Computer Modern, the italic font tries to be as cursive as possible: italic type originally was an imitation of handwriting. For other fonts it's not so.

If you want a distinctive shape, you may prefer slanted type for the “p”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\momentum}{%
  \mathord{% only use in math mode
    \text{\usefont{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{sl}p}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$p$ $\momentum$

$\dot{\momentum}_{\parallel}=e\overline{E_{\parallel}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

To be honest, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Right. Physics is defined by content and context, not by font.